# NOT IN in Mysql doesn't returns needed values - Subquery included

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

**I Got this tables:**  Warehouse, Employee

**Employee:** 5 employees created, with id_employee, firstname, lastname, etc.

**Warehouse:** *(in brackets, values on every row)*

Row 1: *id_warehouse (1)  -  id_employee (1)*

Row 2: *id_warehouse (2)  -  id_employee (2)*

Row 3: *id_warehouse (3)  -  id_employee (2)*

Row 4: *id_warehouse (4)  -  id_employee (2)*

**I GOT this MySQL-Phpmyadmin- Query. I want to receive all these employees that are not connected to a warehouse... Help please... What's that bad?** There's no problems with employee table, I'm pretty sure of that.

```
SELECT de.id_employee, CONCAT(de.lastname,' ',de.firstname) as name 
FROM employee de
WHERE de.id_employee NOT IN (SELECT id_employee FROM warehouse GROUP BY id_employee)
```

**The problem is, that after execute this, I receive 0 or no values, no employees, but I must receive the employees 3, 4 and 5.**

Comment: Please post you data sets

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NOT IN` is dangerous with subqueries.  If even one value in the subquery returns `NULL`, then no rows are returned.

For this reason, I strongly encourage the use of `NOT EXISTS` instead.  So, phrase your query as:

```
SELECT de.id_employee, CONCAT(de.lastname,' ',de.firstname) as name 
FROM employee de
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM warehouse w
                  WHERE de.id_employee = w.id_employee
                 );
```

Another advantage is that this will have better performance, particularly if you have an index on `warehouse(id_employee)`.

Comment: it returns me nothing anyway ... but, what means "SELECT 1"... ?

Comment: @AyQuerico . . . That returns a single column in the result set.  `EXISTS` only cares whether rows are returned, not the values in the columns on that row.

Comment: but i need that values, a list of employees, and NOT EXISTS or NOT IN returns me the same 0 rows

Comment: In that case, all employees in `employee` are in `warehouse`.

Comment: oh dfidnf though got 5, dunno why have 2 ... uff my bad sry ... and thanks for aclaration for make this better with no exists